# AngularJS - resource - doas a request have to be inside $scope.$apply?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope, angularjs-service

I could not find anything in the docs about this, but it seems that any request has to be inside a `$apply()` call - (wether this `$apply()` call comes from an action or is invoked manually).

I can not explain this strange behavior any other way:

```
// inside a controller
$scope.resources = Resource.query(); 
// a request gets sent
```

works just fine, but

```
// somewhere else - in a callback for auto-complete 
// just to show that this is outside $scope.$apply() - not realy setTimeout
setTimeout(function(){ 

  $scope.resources = Resource.query();

},100);
// no request gets sent;

});
```

Comment: Are you sure that no request gets sent, or is it just that your view is not updated?

Comment: @JosephSilber I am shure, but I am using development version (1.1.4 of angular & angular-resource)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are looking at this issue: https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/2371.
You may want to follow up.